# using "this way" in this sentence

Tags: adverbs, definite-article

Consider

> Nowadays, computer games are **the** children's hobbies....
>
> Children **this way** spend most of their time by themselves without contacting with other kids

First, is the first "the" correct?
Second, is it a correct use of "this way"? Should it be:

> in this way, .....

Comment: Your first sentence would only be "correct" (i.e. - "natural" in easily-imagined contexts) if the word ***the*** is stressed in speech (or bolded / italicised in writing) AND if ***hobbies*** is changed to singular ***hobby***. Then it would constitute an assertion that the ***top, most important*** children's hobby is playing computer games. ***This way*** in the second sentence looks clumsy, because there isn't really a clearly-specified "prior referent" to which it can refer (presumably you mean *children passing their time playing computer games [like this?]*, but it doesn't really work).

Comment: Right, you don't want **the** children's hobbies, simply "children's hobbies".   And assuming that the two sentences appear one after another:  "Children spend most of their time *in this way*, playing by themselves, having no contact with other kids."  (without contacting with... is a little awkward).

Comment: @tromano in your sentence does *in this way* refers to its following? Or do you suppose it as *playing computer games* in aforementioned sentence?

Answer (score 2):

To use "the children" is the common usage husbands and wives use when speaking to each other or to close family or friends when whose children they are is obvious. If speaking to someone that won't assume you are speaking of your children, then say "my children." "Our children" is sometimes used, and it kind of bridges the divide. It depends on the hearer knowing that "our children" means "my wife's and my children" which would sound awkward and not "my children and your children and the whole office's children" or such which of course can usually be said with "everybody's children" when who's everybody is obvious.

If you are speaking of children in general or children in this country, "the children" is the best choice. This concept is the general usage. With groups, politicians sometimes use American as a modifier as in "the wealthiest Americans," "American families," etc. but this is such a narrow usage that hearing it identifies the speaker as an activist and tells you which party as well.

*In this way* or *this way* both sound fine if placed at the beginning of the sentence and set off with a comma. Try these usages:

> This way, children spend most of their time by themselves without contacting with other kids.
>
> In this way, children spend most of their time by themselves without contacting with other kids.

Also, change "contacting with" to "interacting with" as in "I contacted my friend so our children could have more interaction with their peers during the school vacation."

Comment: *If you are speaking of children in general or children in this country, "the children" is the best choice*, Do you mean is NOT the best choice?

Comment: No. Perhaps, I should say it is acceptable rather than the best. Often, "children" alone is better in those circumstances.